# WPF components rapid connectivity with DB like Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

In Windows Forms, we connect components and grids with Data Adapters and just drag drop and selection, but i dont find such thing in WPF, may be i dont know, but i am using the approach of LINQ and i write code in MainWindow, but for large applications, it will eat my development time, is there such approach in which we connect SQL with combo and grids, just like Data adapters etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I bind a database to a ListView in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364008/how-do-i-bind-a-database-to-a-listview-in-wpf)