# How do I bind a database to a ListView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, database, listview, binding

I have some data (about 1000 rows) that I want to display. I want the user to be able to filter and sort the data dynamicly. Also I have to be able to save and load the data. I am relativly new to databases and need your help deciding which approach is the best/most resonable:

1st variant:
This is my current approach. I am using a ListView/GridView that is bound to a ObservableCollection of RowItems. I can now use the View to sort and filter. Saving and loading is done via Serialisation.

2nd variant:
Use of a database to store the data. The data is then loaded into the same business objects as above.

3rd variant:
Bind the ListView directly to a database. I just found out that this is somehow possible and am still somewhat hazy on the details. Especially on the aspect of sorting and filtering (Could that be done via a database Query?)

4th variant:
Store data in database. Use ObservableCollection of bussines objects for binding. But filter (and sort?) via SQL query.

These are the ideas I have to fullfilling my requirements. I'd like to know which one is the best/easiest/best performed/etc. or if you suggest an other approach.`enter code here`

Comment: Be careful binding directly to the database as some WPF controls will lazy load the data. What this means for your application is that as the user scrolls through the list, WPF will make more database calls which can make the GUI stutter.

Comment: @Wer2: My motivation for binding to directly to a database is that I have to hold all data in memory otherwise. Or is that not such a big disadvantage as I think?

Comment: It depends on how large your dataset is. If your data is to large to hold in memory, you might want to consider loading it in chunks and not letting WPF handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter, there are couple of points you need to consider:

- Where possible never make tight integration between back end data and display. Makes it easier to change either later on. you can use NHibernate or other ORM to make it easier to represent and read/write data from database. That way you have layer/tier in between them (aka n-tier)
- you will only need to make call to DB for reading the data, it is 1000 rows it is not too bad, you can read them in one go and keep it in memory. Any filtering/sorting/grouping that you can do it on the in memory DomainModel/Buisness Object without touching the library.

i would use mixture of variant 1) and 2).

I would use business object to represent your data from Database (NHibernate is quite handy). I would then perform all data filtering/sorting on the client without requering DB each time. Any writes to the database must go through some sort of Domain Model layer or ORM so that they are not tighly linked. That allows to me to chnage DB without effecting the GUI Front end